# Lyx nested environments

Tags: environments, lyx

I would like to put an enumerated list into the body of a Lemma environment, in Lyx. This is what I would have:

```
Lemma 1. First line of the statement
    i)  condition 1
    ii) condition 2
  last line of the statement.
Proof. .......
```

But when I set "enumerated list" for the two central lines, then the last line (before proof) is shown as a separated Lemma:

```
Lemma 1. First line of the statement
    i)  condition 1
    ii) condition 2
Lemma 2. last line of the statement.
Proof. .......
```

Comment: In addition to the desired output, please add a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-told-i-have-to-write-a-minimal-example-what-is-that) that illustrates your problem.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

As explained in section **3.4 Nesting Environments** of *Lyx User's Manual*, you can nest environments simply selecting the inner environment and applying *Increase Depth* from the toolbar.

Answer (score 3):

that is a problem with the way how LyX works, it inserts an empty line. You can try to use the LaTeX mode inside LyX. Hit `Ctrl-L` after the word in the first line of the Lemma where you want to insert the enumerate list. Then insert in the red box

```
\enumerate \item condition \item another \endenumerate
```

then move the cursore out of the box, hit enter and write the following text of the Lemma.