# Nested Environment in LyX: Theorem with only an enumeration

Tags: lyx, environments, nesting

I've read the following posts but I'm not sure they answer my doubt: [Lyx nested environments](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/39012/lyx-nested-environments); [Normalizing nested environments for cleaner design (LyX)](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/319945/normalizing-nested-environments-for-cleaner-design-lyx).

I am using the AMS theorem environment, and I want to start a theorem *immediately* followed by an enumeration (ie. with no text in the first line following *Theorem*. In LaTeX, I would type:

```
\begin{theorem}
\begin{enumerate}
\item Bla Bla Bla
\end{enumerate}
\end{theorem}
```

I know you can nest environments in LyX, but it is not letting me leave the theorem environment empty. How can I have the *Theorem* show up, and immediately start the list?

Comment: Already answered here: [`theorem` environment : interaction with `enumerate`/`itemize`](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/319717)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Go to Document > Settings > Local Layout and enter the following:

```
ModifyStyle Theorem
    KeepEmpty 1
End
```

Then click on the "Validate" button, and then "OK". Now it should work as you want, but has a (likely undesired) consequence: when you are done writing your theorem, you can't get back to standard by just pressing <kbd>Return</kbd> a couple of times, because the `KeepEmpty` change means that we can enter empty lines in the Theorem environment. So to get back to Standard, you have to manually select the "Standard" layout from the drop-down box in the upper-left (or just use the shortcut <kbd>alt + p, s</kbd>).

For more information, if you are ready to jump down a rabbit hole, go to Help > Customization in LyX.

Answer (score 2):

**To have the enumeration start on a new line:**

You can use `\phantom{}` to avoid the empty theorem text, while not providing an output.

Start the theorem environment, enter math mode and type `\phantom`, then press `return`. Then enter some text in the phantom box.

Move cursor to after the math mode box, and press <kbd>Return</kbd> for a new line. Choose `enumerate` layout in the dropdown, and press <kbd>Tab</kbd> to nest it in the theorem environment.

Having finsihed the enumeration, press <kbd>Return</kbd> twice to go back to the theorem environment, where you can the choose a different layout---e.g. `proof`.

In LyX, you get something like the following, with the `phantomed` not showing in the compiled.

[image]

**Note:** LyX has rich keyboard shortcut customization that we can use to insert the `\phantom` in a less fiddly manner: Go to `Tools > Preferences > Editing > Shortcuts > New` and in the `Function` field, insert `math-insert \phantom{.}` and assign it a shortcut.

**Without new line:**

Perhaps you are interested in an output identical to that of this MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\newtheorem{theorem}{Theorem}

\begin{document}
\begin{theorem}
\begin{enumerate}
\item Bla Bla Bla
\item Bla Bla Bla
\end{enumerate}
\end{theorem}
\end{document}
```

This compiles without the itemization starting on a new line:

[image]

To obtain this in LyX, you can label the theorem (`Insert > Label`) or insert an empty theorem title using an TeX code insert (`Insert > TeX Code`) with content `[]`. The label option would look like this in LyX, and compiles as the above MWE:

[image]

Comment: Thanks for your answer. is there no alternative? This, while it does work, seems a bit fiddly.

Comment: @scottkosty provides an alternative :) 
I've edited my answer to include info on assigning a keyboard shortcut, as well as something that closer resembles the code you provided.

Comment: This answer is good and more general than the approach I gave, since you could use the shortcut for any similar layout without having to change anything in the local layout.